# Cloudera Manager - Kerberos Active Directory setup ldapsearch AD_SERVER not populating

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, openldap, cloudera-manager

I am trying to do setup of Kerberos with AD using Cloudera Manager on my Cluster. On the step after where we specify user name and password it is giving error for ldap_sasl_bind (-1) error. I have tried to look around and done the settings for AD in all the nodes. It is still not working.

Than I have tried ldapsearch command from SSH surprisingly it is working fine. so Node setup is correct nothing require there. I think.

I have further debugged it that using Cloudera Manager log and found out ldapsearch command is having “ldap://:636″. I am getting nothing in AD_SERVER parameter which is being used in /usr/share/cmf/bin/import_credentials.sh.

1. My Certificate imported correctly.
2. My Certificate has valid subject line.
3. I have valid user with manage permission.

What am i missing?

Thanks,
BS

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never,

I had the same issue with the wizard. Turns out some settings are not exported properly by Cloudera Manager during wizard execution.

What works for me; go to Settings -> Kerberos. Force a save of the settings by changing one option (Active Directory LDAPS Port from 636 to 637 to 636 again) and then rerun the wizard.

After that Configuration what correctly set for me.

Best of luck.